# How to create multidimensional hash like structure

Tags: tcl

What is the best way to create and access multidimensional hashes in TCL that are present in perl for example:

```
if{ $line = (\D+) ....} {
$hash{name}=$1
$hash{height}=$2
}
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

You can either use composite keys like this (the neatest option in the simplest cases):

```
set x 1
set y 2
set d($x,$y) 3
```

Or you can put a dictionary in an array element:

```
set x 1
set y 2
dict set d($x) $y 3
```

Or you can use a nested dictionary:

```
set x 1
set y 2
dict set d $x $y 3
```

There are some subtleties about the differences between them, but most of the time most people's code doesn't really care and doesn't need to care.

**Here's the case where you are most likely to need to care.** If you're doing the first option and you can't make guarantees about what characters might be in the atomic keys, you can use `list` to build the overall key (as that knows how to apply quoting rules to avoid confusion):

```
set x "the quick, cunning brown fox"
set y "the ever-so, ever-so lazy dog"
set d([list $x $y]) "jumps over"
```

Of course, that makes access more awkward as you *need* to use `list` (or another list-building command) when building the keys (or have the right string literals, which is annoying for larger keys). The other two options have no problems at all with confusing arbitrary keys; dictionaries had not getting mixed up over such things as an explicit design goal.

Comment: Technically, Perl code is mostly like using dictionaries, except Perl has quite different value semantics so it's not really like that at all…